# how to bind input in ember using handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I've just started with ember. Trying to make the first app. Just wanna bind the input textbox value inside a h1 tag. But it's not working. Here is the code

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="helloEmber">
    <div>
     <label>Name:</label>
     {{input type="text" value=name placeholder="Enter your name"}}
    </div>
    <div class="text">
    <h1>My name is {{name}} and I want to learn Ember!</h1>
    </div>
</script>

<!-- libraries -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ember/ember.js"></script>
```

I didn't write any JS. If I open this index.html file, I find it blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `Em.Application` instance to begin with ember.
[DOCS](http://emberjs.com/guides/application/) here

Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/vPm3x/1/)

Comment: thanks a lot for replying. But I have one doubt. If in the html file I change the data-template-name="application" to something else, like data-template-name="myApp", than the code is not working. So what should I do for that?

Comment: The application template is the default template that is rendered when your application starts. However you could change that by specifying `templateName` for `ApplicationView`... http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/vPm3x/2/ ... But it wont be necessary in most cases